# dispay image in multiple sizes

Tags: php, image, gd

i am trying to add some text to images and display it using gd in php in different sizes. i know how to display 1 image. here is the code.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
}

else{
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$img_src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($file));
$img_dest = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);
$src_width = imagesx($img_src);
$src_height = imagesy($img_src);
imagecopyresized($img_dest, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, $src_width, $src_height);

$text = $_POST['text'];
$font_path = 'arial.TTF';
$black = imagecolorallocate($img_dest, 0, 0, 0);
imagettftext($img_dest, 25, 0, 302, 62, $grey, $font_path, $text);
imagettftext($img_dest, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font_path, $text);
header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $img_dest );
imagedestroy( $img_dest );
imagedestroy( $img_src );
}
?>
```

but how do i display more than 1 in the same page, the same image but in different size

please tel me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create each image for itself. With modifying the image like you do there it is not possible because you return an image as an object.

If you have write access to you webserver you can save the other generated images, e.g.

```
$src_w = 100;
$src_h = 100;

$img_50perc = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w / 2, $src_h / 2);
imagecopyresized($img_50perc, $img_dest, 0, 0, 0, 0, $src_w/2, $src_h/2, $src_w, $src_h);

$img_25perc = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w / 4, $src_h / 4);
imagecopyresized($img_25perc, $img_dest, 0, 0, 0, 0, $src_w/4, $src_h/4, $src_w, $src_h);
```

and then you may save the image:

```
imagepng($img_dest, 'dest_folder/myfile_100perc.png');
imagepng($img_50perc, 'dest_folder/myfile_50perc.png');
imagepng($img_25perc, 'dest_folder/myfile_25perc.png');
```

You may create the images during the creation of the php page you can create from these filenames dynamically img-tags

```
echo '100 Percent of size: <img src="dest_folder/myfile_100perc" />';
echo '50 Percent of size: <img src="dest_folder/myfile_50perc" />';   
echo '25 Percent of size: <img src="dest_folder/myfile_25perc" />';
```

Another way to do so is to create each image by its own and resize by a parameter given to the php-script

```
100%: <img src="myImageResizer.php?faktor=1" />
50%:  <img src="myImageResizer.php?faktor=2" />
25%:  <img src="myImageResizer.php?faktor=4" />
```

and then calculating the dest-size by that given faktor

```
$faktor = $_GET['faktor'];
if (!$faktor || !is_numeric($faktor)) $faktor = 1;
$src_w = 100 / $faktor;
$src_h = 100 / $faktor;
```